# Weight scaler in android

Tags: android

When we take input from the user we normally use the edit text view in android. How to make weight scaler in which the user can select his weight as shown in the figure?

[image: Weight Scaler to take input from user]

Answer (score 1):

It's a quite complicated task, you will have to draw a custom view (a circle combined with an arc, draw the arc over the circle). Draw ticks on the circle every 1° (from 1° to 360°). This repository may help you: https://github.com/ngallazzi/MeterView

Comment: Thanks for your comment dear, Here I am interested that slidable arc from 0 to 180 degrees is shown to user and the user select his weight by sliding the arc forward or backward.